# Using `implicit def`

Tags: scala, typeclass

Given a made-up `F` type-class:

```
scala> trait F[A] {}
defined trait F
```

and this definition, which uses a `context bound` to require that the input `A` has a type-class instance of `F`:

```
scala> def f[A : F](x: A) = ???
f: [A](x: A)(implicit evidence$1: F[A])Nothing
```

I defined a `Person` and type-class instance:

```
scala> case class Person(name: String)
defined class Person

scala> implicit val person: F[Person] = new F[Person] {}
person: F[Person] = $anon$1@262b2c86
```

And the following compiles:

```
scala> f(Person("foo"))
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
```

But, there's no `String` implementation, so it fails.

```
scala> f("foobar")
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type F[String]
       f("foobar")
        ^
```

I then defined an `F[String]` using:

```
scala> implicit def fInstance(x: String) = new F[String] {}
fInstance: (x: String)F[String]
```

But, I can't run:

```
scala> f("foobar")
<console>:18: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type F[String]
       f("foobar")
        ^
```

since I do not have an implicit `F[String]`, but rather a `String => F[String]`.

What's the proper way to use such an `implicit def` to meet the `F[String]` constraint, i.e. call the `f` function successfully with a type of `String`?

I got it to work via:

```
scala> implicit val x: F[String] = implicitly[String => F[String]].apply("foobar")
x: F[String] = $anon$1@7b7fdc8

scala> f("foobar")
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:230)
  at .f(<console>:12)
  ... 33 elided
```

But I'm not sure if it's the right/clean way to do it.

Comment: This is really hard to answer without knowing what information and operations the type class is meant to capture, but given this particular `F`, you could define a `String` instance in exactly the same way you did the `Person` instance.

Comment: For this case, I can only construct an `F[String]` if provided a `String`, i.e. an `F[String]` instance depends upon a `String` argument.

Comment: As a follow-up, is it bad to use an `implicit` outside of a companion class, i.e. an orphan `implicit` instance?

Comment: `fInstance` is not a typeclass instance, but an implicit conversion

Answer (score 1):

You defined an implicit conversion. If you want to use a def to provide typeclass instances you just write the same as you'd write an implicit val but replace val with def.

```
implicit def fInstance = new F[String] {}
```

Normally you only use a def if you need type parameters, like here.

```
implicit def fInstance[A] = new F[List[A]] {}
```

Or

```
implicit def fInstance[A](implicit ev: F[A]) = new F[List[A]] {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `fInstance` defines an implicit conversion, i.e. a way to turn a `String` into `F[String]`. For generating a typeclass instance, a method accepting implicit parameters can be used:

```
implicit def fInstance(implicit x: String) = new F[String] {}
```

it is typically used in FP libraries to derive one typeclass from another:

```
implicit def optionMonoid[A](implicit S: Semigroup[A]): Monoid[Option[A]] = ???
// or, which is the same
// implicit def optionMonoid[A: Semigroup]: Monoid[Option[A]] = ???
```

The idea is that `F[String]` can operate on any String in general, not being dependent on actual arguments provided into function. Of course, you can always provide instances explicitly:

```
f("foobar")(new F[String] { })
```

As a follow-up, the important part of typeclasses is that you can define them ad-hoc, i.e. not having access to definitions of `F` and `String` at all, and you are forced to scope implicits in Scala and import them, so it's totally ok.

Comment: `and you are forced to scope implicits in Scala and import them, so it's totally ok.` Could you please say more as to how this statement applies (or does not) to orphan `implicit`'s?

Comment: @KevinMeredith you are not allowed to simply write a `def` or `val` in the source (if it's application code and not Scala script) — it has to belong to an object or class. So you have to go with `object Implicits { implicit def fString: F[String] = ??? }`, but you cannot use it in other code, unless you do `import Implicits.fString` in it before using.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler version of your definition (and you can remove `implicit` from `fInstance`):

```
implicit val singleFInstance: F[String] = fInstance("") // or fInstance("foobar"), etc.
```

Whether this is the right thing to do, very much depends on what `F` and `f` are supposed to mean.

But generally speaking: if `F` is really a type-class, `fInstance(string)` gives different results depending on the string (not just different instances, but different behavior), and `f`'s signature is correct, then this is wrong and you should accept that calling `f("foobar")` isn't meaningful.